# **kwargs vs 10 arguments in a python function?

Tags: python, xml, ebay-api

I am starting out with python and trying to construct an XML request for an [ebay web service](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/best-match-item-details/CallRef/findBestMatchItemDetailsAcrossStores.html):

Now, my question is:

Say, this is my function:

```
def findBestMatchItemDetailsAcrossStores():
     request = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <findBestMatchItemDetailsAcrossStoresRequest xmlns="http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services">
     <siteResultsPerPage>50</siteResultsPerPage>
     <entriesPerPage>50</entriesPerPage>
     <ignoreFeatured>true</ignoreFeatured>
     <keywords>ipod</keywords> <-----REQUIRED
     <itemFilter>
     <paramName>PriceMin</paramName>
     <paramValue>50</paramValue>
     <name>Currency</name>
     <value>USD</value>
     </itemFilter>
     <itemFilter>
     <paramName>PriceMax</paramName>
     <paramValue>100</paramValue>
     </itemFilter>
     </findBestMatchItemDetailsAcrossStoresRequest>"""
     return get_response(findBestMatchItemDetailsAcrossStores.__name__, request)
```

Where, keyword is  the only required field. So, how should I construct the method? The ways can be:

1. Create an object, pass it to the func(object) : The java way
2. Pass all the arguments: func(a=val1, b=val2, c=val3, d=val4 etc)
3. Use **kwargs and trust the person who calls the function, that he passes the right keys with the values, because I will use the keys to actually construct the XML tags.

**Update:**

All the xml tags you see in the request are needed to be passed by the user. But keywords *should* be passed and others maybe passed if required.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What fields do other functions need to be able to change?

Comment: didn't get that. all of these fields are only local to this function.

Comment: In other words, what fields does the program need to specify on the fly?

Comment: Well, all the fiends in the string request should be passed by the user of the method. The only diff is, all the fields are optional except `<keywords>ipod</keywords>`, which is mandatory.

Comment: I think this is a case of "explicit is better"

Comment: @gnibbler so, in that case: how should I construct the string? check and add?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A good idea is to put all the parameters with appropriate defaults (or just `None` defaults) in the function signature. Yeah, it will require a little more typing in the function itself, but the interface will be clean, self-documented and simple to use, as you won't have to look up possible parameters in ebay docs or function source. It will save you time later on.

Comment: yeah, I am also in favor of this approach, i.e. approach 2.

Comment: Agree. `**kwargs` is primarily useful when you don't know ahead-of-time what argument names you're expecting (see, eg, `str.format`). If you're expecting particular arguments, it is better to specify them explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

how about modeling the message as a class?

```
class FindBestMatchItemDetailsAcrossStoresRequest:
     def __init__(self,keywords):
         self.keywords = keywords # required parameters in the constructor
         # set up the default values....etc
         self.siteResultsPerPage = 50 
         self.name = 'Currency'


     def send(self):
         # build message from self.xxx
         return get_response()


 #usage
 req = FindBestMatchItemDetailsAcrossStoresRequest('ipod')
 response = req.send()

 #usage with optional args

 req.siteResultsPerPage = 150
 response = req.send()
```

Comment: I would like to know too, this looks like good to me. But I am not aware about the pythonic ways.

Comment: Presumably, you meant `req = FindBestMatchItemDetailsAcrossStoresRequest('ipod')`?

Comment: updated my question. I think you misunderstood my question. In this case, what if the user wants to pass: siteResultsPerPage? how will I achieve that?

Comment: @Johnsyweb It would throw TypeError, as Gareth forgot the `self`'s. Also, i don't see the point of using a class over, say, a defaultdict.

Answer (score 0):

I would use named parameters for all. By doing this it is very easy to assign default values, and to force the user to supply required parameters (by omitting the default)